# How can i achieve player movement like in this game in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and started making games recently. I am making a line game and trying to replicate player movement like in this game
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ThirdState.SineLine&hl=en_IN&gl=US
Basically, I want the player's body to move in the curve when swiped left or right as it does in this game.
Can anyone please guide me through it? (I am coding in C#)
Thanks

Comment: From the video it seems that horizontal movement is not controlled (it is just a sine wave) while player can hold the vertical movement.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use sine function.
[sine function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPg1f.png)

so you just need to apply the function to your current time, and multiply it with the speed, And apply the result to your player x position, and put a simple function to make the player move up when get touched. with it, you can achieve the similiar movement like the game you mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve the excact same affect, your best bet is to use physics. First attach a movement script to the player. Now, in the start function, get the component, rigidbody2d. Next, in the fixedupdate function, add a force on the x axis(both left and right i mean). Then in the update function, check if the player position is at X:14 or X:1 for example. And if the player is in X:14, then add a small force that makes the player go to the other side and vice versa. After that, make another of statement checking if the player swiped left or right. If so add some force on the z axis and a bit on the y axis. I said to add some force on the y axis to makes
that curve you were talking about. If you see jittery movement, try moving this if statement into the fixedupdate function.

Hope this helps a bit! :D